# How to replace text in curly brackets with another text based on comparisons using Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am quiet new to regular expressions. I have a string that looks like this:

```
str = "abc/def/([default], [testing])"
```

and a dictionary

```
dict = {'abc/def/[default]' : '2.7', 'abc/def/[testing]' : '2.1'}
```

and using Python RE, I want str in this form, after comparisons of each element in dict to str:

```
str = "abc/def/(2.7, 2.1)"
```

Any help how to do it using Python RE?

P.S. its not the part of any assignment, instead it is the part of my project at work and I have spent many hours to figure out solution but in vain.

Comment: is regex do a string comparision?

Comment: Can there be any other prefix than `abc/def/`?

Comment: I don't suppose `str = str.replace("[default]", "2.7").replace("[testing]", "2.1")` would work well enough?

Comment: no prefix will remain same like abc/def/

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Can we just ignore the `abc/def/` prefix or does it matter? Will `[default]` *always* be replaced with `2.7`?

Comment: sorry for my unclear explanations, prefix abc/def/ matters for comparison. [default] will only be replaced by 2.7 if prefix i.e. abc/def/ are same both in str and dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

st = "abc/def/([default], [testing], [something])"
dic = {'abc/def/[default]' : '2.7',
       'abc/def/[testing]' : '2.1',
       'bcd/xed/[something]' : '3.1'}



prefix_regex = "^[\w*/]*"
tag_regex = "\[\w*\]"

prefix = re.findall(prefix_regex, st)[0]
tags = re.findall(tag_regex, st)

for key in dic:
    key_prefix = re.findall(prefix_regex, key)[0]
    key_tag = re.findall(tag_regex, key)[0]
    if prefix == key_prefix:
        for tag in tags:
            if tag == key_tag:
                st = st.replace(tag, dic[key])

print st
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
abc/def/(2.7, 2.1, [something])
```

Comment: works fine as per my question but it neglects comparison of prefix i.e. abc/def/; tag [default] should only be replaced by 2.7 iff prefix abc/def/ in st is equal to abc/def/ in dic. hope you've understand my comment

Comment: Got it.  The edited code takes the prefix into account.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably not required here. Hope this helps

```
lhs,rhs = str.split("/(")                                          
rhs1,rhs2 = rhs.strip(")").split(", ")                             
lhs+="/"                                                           
print "{0}({1},{2})".format(lhs,dict[lhs+rhs1],dict[lhs+rhs2])
```

**output**

```
abc/def/(2.7,2.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `re` module.

Hypotheses :

- there is a dictionary whose keys are composed of a prefix and a variable part, the variable part is enclosed in brackets (`[]`)
- the values are strings by which the variable parts are to be replaced in the string
- the string is composed by a prefix, a `(`, a list of variable parts and a `)`
- the variable parts in the string are enclosed in `[]`
- the variable parts in the string are separated by a comma followed by optional spaces

Python code :

```
import re

class splitter:
    pref = re.compile("[^(]+")
    iden = re.compile("\[[^]]*\]")
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def split(self, s):
        m = self.pref.match(s)
        if m is not None:
            p = m.group(0)
            elts = self.iden.findall(s, m.span()[1])
            return p, elts
        return None
    def convert(self, s):
        p, elts = self.split(s)
        return p + "(" + ", ".join((self.d[p + elt] for elt in elts)) + ")"
```

Usage :

```
s = "abc/def/([default], [testing])"
d = {'abc/def/[default]' : '2.7', 'abc/def/[testing]' : '2.1'}
sp = splitter(d)
print(sp.convert(s))
```

output :

```
abc/def/(2.7, 2.1)
```